# Matlab integral2 reached maximum number of functions

Tags: matlab

I want to compute this integral

```
integral2(function,0,a,0,2*pi)
```

where

```
function = @(R,PHI) (e_r(R,PHI).*E_R(R,PHI) + e_phi(R,PHI).*E_PHI(R,PHI)).*R;
```

and I get the warning

```
Warning: Reached the maximum number of function evaluations (10000). The result fails the global error test.
```

the problem I think it is inside the `E_R(R,PHI)` and `E_PHI(R,PHI)` functions because are a made by constant parameters and the two variables `R` and `PHI`

```
E_R = @(R,PHI) (Ex*cos(PHI) + Ey*sin(PHI)) .* exp(1i*k*R.*cos(phi_inc-PHI).*sin(theta_inc));
E_PHI = @(R,PHI) (-Ex*sin(PHI) + Ey*cos(PHI)) .* exp(1i*k*R.*cos(phi_inc-PHI).*sin(theta_inc));
```

here `Ex, Ey` are complex numbers that I choose, `k` is given `phi_inc` and `theta_inc` are given angles in radians.

I don't understand this warning since I'm just integrating constants multiplied by something that depends on the variable where I'm integrating.

To solve it I use `integral2(function,0,a,0,2*pi,'method','iterated')` or even `tiled` seams to work but it takes too a lot to compute. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** actually the problem appears when I change `theta_inc` which describe the incidence a field to a surface. If i use `theta_inc = 0` since the whole exponent of the exponential becomes zero there are no problems, but for an angle greater than `0°` the simulation give me that warning. 
Could be due to errors in the model that I'm using to describe the incidence of a field?

Comment: This may help: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2014/02/12/double-integration-in-matlab-methods-and-handling-discontinuities-singularities-and-more/

Comment: Already saw that. I took from there the iterated and tiled method. I also used quad2d choosing the converging point (above 10000 by default for integral2) but it is not sufficient or it takes a lot of time. I would also like to know you think there are some singular points in my functions (I don't think so, since are just constant multiplied by sine and cosine). In this way I can solve te problem mathematically by hand and keep using integral2